# Eclipse with $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I have some library files built using JNI in the directory /usr/local/lib/.

If i start the Eclipse from luncher, the path is never picked up by Eclipse, so I need to specify -Djava.library.path to the Run Configurations.

But if I start the Eclipse from command line. It seems working fine.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this and How to configure it to known the /usr/local/lib/ path from luncher. Thanks.

I am using Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2, on Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is probably because your shell executes `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` in one of the startup scripts.

The launcher doesn't run those, so the variable isn't set.

The workaround: Write a small script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and starts Eclipse (use `exec eclipse` if you want to avoid a useless process hanging around until Eclipse exits).

Alternatively, edit `eclipse.ini` and add `-Djava.library.path=...` after `-vmargs`

To verify that this works, open Help / About Eclipse / Installation Details / Configuration. The path should show up in the dialog as a System property.

Comment: I am using eclipse. Could you please guide me to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the eclipse configuration?

Comment: In `eclipse.ini`, add `-Djava.library.path=...` after `-vmargs` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092003/how-do-i-modify-eclipses-library-path

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but for PERL not java. what should I type in my `eclipse.ini` , I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think for PERL, you need a star script which sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.