# How do I modify Eclipse's library.path?

Tags: eclipse, ide, java.library.path

I have rather perhaps general question...
I am using Eclipse as my IDE...  When I go to 
->HELP  ->ABOUT ECLIPSE SDK  ->INSTALLATION DETAILS ->CONFIGURATION, 
I see the line entries:
**-Djava.class.path**=C:\Eclipse\etc... 
and 
**java.library.path**=C:\Eclipse\etc...

I have two questions on this...
1)  What does -Djava.class.path mean in the context of ECLIPSE environment?
2)  How do I alter/modify java.library.path option for eclipse, so that the changes that I make are visible in the eclipse's configuration window under HELP menu as outlined above?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
-Djava.library.path=" something"...
```

or you can  simply add `-Djava.library.path=yourPath` to the `eclipse.ini.`

Comment: Hi, Ravindra: 
I actually tried this one many times before posting my question...
In short, it does not work...
Your suggestion is perfect when doing straight java, but in eclipse it does not work for some reason.  feels to me that eclipse is ignoring the command you are suggesting...

Any other ideas?

thanks!!

Comment: @JavaFan:Window->
  Preferences->
    Java->
      Installed JREs

Comment: @JavaFan: goto above menu & change

Comment: I also tried this as well before... it does not work...
Putting the -Djava.library.path = in there does not alter anything in the  configuration window at HELP//ABOUT ECLIPSE//INSTALLATION DETAILS//CONFIGURATION tab(window)...

perhaps there are other methods that need to be invoked?

Comment: @JavaFan: Did you put this option after `-vmargs`?

Comment: yes I tried this, and does not appear to propagate across of the plugins, for example, BIRT.  do you have any suggestions?