# Adding an .so file to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I want to do add a `.so` file to my project. Currently I have my `.so` file on my desktop in a folder with the Eclipse environment pointed to it like so:

[image: class folders on buildpath]

As you can see my native source item is pointing to the correct location, but I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

This is how my class path looks when I print it out:

```
/correct-path/opencv-2.4.9/build/lib:/correct-path/facerec
```

Comment: Native libraries have to go in the [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6666696/2970947); not the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've added this to my eclipse.ini `-Djava.library.path="/correct-path/facerec"` is this correct? It hasn't mad a difference.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Afraid that didn't work...

Comment: @user3238439 Double check that the library has the same bitness as Java.  That is, if the library is 32-bit, make sure the JRE is not 64-bit, or vice versa.

Comment: @user3238439 The setting should not go in eclipse.ini, but in your Run Configuration under the Arguments tab, in the "VM arguments" area. When you run an application a new JVM is spawned which needs your library path.