# Add java path to python project

Tags: java, python, django

I have a Django project which need access to the `libjvm.so` located at:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/
```

I keep getting unresolved imports in pydev. When I try this in terminal everything imports fine.

I have tried adding the path mentioned above to `Properties>PyDev - PYTHONPATH>external libraries`.

What can I do to resolve these imports?

Comment: This is a guess, but have you tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244418/set-ld-library-path-before-importing-in-python may be related.

Comment: @rkersh I have tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666696/eclipse-with-ld-library-path and to no avail